# Does the RPG Stack have a forum, and if not, would it be possible to make one?

Tags: discussion

The question is in the title. Is there a forum for the RPG stack exchange, and if not, would it be possible to have one made? And I mean specifically a forum, and not a chat.

If there isn't one, then why not? There are already Many RPG forums out there, true, but none of them are directly linked to this website. There are a lot of questions I've seen here that often get a comment to the effect of "this is a discussion question." While I understand that's not what this site is for, what would be the harm in having a forum that we could then send those questions to, possibly to either be changed to a better version, or to give the person asking the discussion they actually want, with the community they want it from.

Also, yes, I understand the Chat does that already. However, it's much harder to use than a forum, because it makes time an issue.

Answer (score 17):

> what would be the harm in having a forum that we could then send those questions to

It would be a distraction from the point of the RPG Stack.

As you say, [there are already lots of RPG forums out there](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). The only people populating this hypothetical one would be *us*, which would draw our attention away from asking and answering questions. A forum wouldn't improve the site, and would have a high potential for making it *less* useful.

Comment: It would be no less distracting than the sum total of the rest of the internet, but yeah, they would add nothing for us

Comment: @Tritium21 Actually, you are wrong, they would add a lot for a lot of players. The problem of RPG.SE is that, opposing technically-themed SE, many more questions are at least partially opinion-based, but still very important. Yes, a forum linked to SE could draw some attention from the Q&A section, but I presume that it will just gather all SE users' attention already dedicated to forums in one place. It will also be very helpful because if an opinion-based question is asked on SE, it could be automatically moved to a forum section, which is obviously useful for the asker.

Comment: Plus, forums tend to die out eventually, and if we link users to other forums, there is a good chance that after some time RPG.SE will survive, but links to the forum will lead nowhere.

Comment: Not going to happen.

Answer (score 7):

There is not one.

There may never be one - this isn't a RPG.SE kind of decision, we're part of a vast network of Stack Exchanges and we use what the Overmind provides.  Stack Exchange generally believes its format is innately superior to forums for questions and answers and wants to maintain the purity of that.

For random discussion - we encourage people to take it to one of the specialized forums. I'm not sure of the value of us endorsing one because there are various with strengths and weaknesses.

(Frankly, I don't spend a lot of time in chat either because to me it's the place where all the noise goes to die, and the reason I stay here on RPG.SE instead of ENWorld, RPG.net, etc. is because I personally hate forums and want the format that keeps things on topic. Briefly helping a noob there is the limit of my patience.)

Although, Jeff Atwood did [announce his "even better forum software" earlier this year](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/02/civilized-discourse-construction-kit.html), [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/). So if you went to meta.SE and sucked up enough and said "Discourse is awesome, can't we have one on SE?" it might not be a zero percent play.