# I just created a thing that needs playtesting. How do I find playtesters among the RPG.SE denizens, or are there other places I should look instead?

Tags: discussion, playtesting

So, you, noble RPG.SE denizen, just created a dungeon.  Or a character class.  Or some house rule.  Of course, like a good and noble DM or amateur developer, you want to play test it before you unleash it on the unsuspecting peasantry.  Is there a "canonical" way to seek out playtesters among our fellow RPG.SE denizens, or is it just a matter of popping into the general chat and asking "I have a thing for system X, does anyone wish to help me playtest it?"

Or should we look in foreign lands for our playtest subjects?

Comment: I've created a [[tag:playtesting]] tag to collect the resources I've found that we already have about playtesting.

Answer (score 18):

### Mainsite and meta aren't set up for this.

We don't allow "Who wants to join my group?" questions for a whole host of reasons, not least of which is that answers will be "Yes, I want to!" and "No, I don't." Not exactly insightful experience-based solutions to a problem you're facing--the answers are useful to YOU but not to anyone else in similar situations who aren't *you.*

> We want the questions on our site to be valuable sources of information for the whole Internet, not just our community members. (from [What Topics Can I Ask About Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

Playtesting solicitation is just a variant on "join my group" and has all the same problems.

### Chat can do it, but not well.

You're free to solicit for playtesters in chat, but you may not get a big response: it's a small, erratic group from all around the world. A joining of interest and availability on a scale large enough to do playtesting is uncommon, since good playtesting needs a fairly wide variety of players and situations in order to usefully evaluate the subject.

### You can ask the main site for *guidance* in finding players, though!

This would actually make a good mainsite question: "I have X system/adventure/whatever, with Y qualities, that I want to test for Z audience. How do I get playtesters?" The Stack *is* set up to provide this kind of assistance. It can be answered through experience; it has clear criteria for voting on whether answers are useful; its advice can be useful to others in similar but not identical situations.

Comment: fortunately, for my case -- chat might be good enough.

Comment: @Shalvenay make a room, name it specifically for what you are testing, then periodically extend invites in main chat, but don't spam

Answer (score 9):

## Chat

The [Role-playing Games Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is where this kind of thing belongs. As nice as it might be to “advertise” it more, to those who might not frequent chat, that would be, ya know, advertising, and it’s not really appropriate for a Q&A.

Of course, [elsewhere](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563) is likely also a good bet, though of course you won’t necessarily get us.