# Could we get a [forum] shortlink?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, magic-links

We get a lot of questions that are better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), and it's customary when closing them to provide a link to that post. Since I've started doing moderation, though, I've noticed that we don't have a shortlink the way we do for [tour], [edit], etc. Could we make that happen to save a bit of time?

Comment: related: [pro forma comments](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3519/23970)

Comment: and likewise related: [premade comment workshopping](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/pre-made-comments-a-resource-gathering-workshopping-thread)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although, as SSD explained, network-wide changes for an RPG.SE-specific code won't happen, there's still a labour-saving work-around available: add a premade comment with the forums link to [the auto-comment script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116).

Answer (score 8):

[Magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/) are hardcoded into the site software itself and as a result are network-wide, not per-site, so although *technically* possible in theory, the likelihood that Staff would add a magic link to every SE in the network that leads to RPG.se's meta about RPG forum alternatives is unsurprisingly *very low*. ;)

Comment: Ah, fair enough. At least now I know!

Answer (score 4):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. We recognize that there's community support for this, but unfortunately, we can't prioritize it at this time.