# Is this the sort of place to ask about game design for my own game?

Tags: support, on-topic

I want to ask about game design for a totally homebrew game I'm doing. But having read the rules it appears the questions are specifically known tabletops. Is asking about how I can design my game against the rules? If so, any suggestions for where else I should look?

Comment: [How much searching have you done?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgame-design%5D+is%3Aquestion) And how *How* is your *How*? That is, do you need help generating ideas or do you need something critiqued?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I did look in that tag but my situation is a bit more niche I think. I suppose its a bit of both. In my game I'm facing a problem with players so I need ideas for how to fix it. The reason I've been unsure is because my game is less a character roleplay and more a roleplay as nations. This is why I was unsure if it'd fit. Its got game elements but its mostly about roleplay.

Comment: The site fields questions about large-scale RPGs like [*Microscope*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/microscope/info) so it should be able to field questions about your homebrew. And questions about how people are playing your game should be on topic as the site fields social questions all the time. You're welcome to be more specific here on Meta than you would on the main site. I mean, you can totally ask here *Can I ask [this question] on the main site?* or even *How can I ask about [this complicated issue] on the main site?* and get help workshopping it *before* you ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Game design questions, broadly speaking, are on-topic. See [game-design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design), and also our [encounter-design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encounter-design), [campaign-design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campaign-design), [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew), and [tags-about-design-im-forgetting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags-about-design-im-forgetting) tags. But they still need to be good Stack-answerable questions, which are sometimes tricky in the world of design.

**Too broad** and **unclear** are likely tripping points. One key when writing questions is to go ahead and be selfish: ask a very specific question. You don't have to worry about making the question too pointed: good *answers* will tend to expound design principles and processes that future readers can leverage for their own uses.

**Idea-generation** is not going to go well. "I want to have ten distinctive tribes of goblins, what should their dress look like?" is the sort of thing [better suited to a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970). Sometimes those questions get re-phrased as "how do I go about designing ten distinctive tribes' garb?" which is passable, but (in my opinion) don't tend to get great answers. If what you're stuck on is coming up with names for goblin tribes, just pop into one of those fora linked above and ask. Not every bit of your homebrew process will fit the stack model.

**When you're not sure** go ahead and make use of our resources. As [HeyICanChan mentioned in a comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7848/is-this-the-sort-of-place-to-ask-about-game-design-for-my-own-game#comment24794_7848) it's always fine to post a "first draft" of a question here on meta to ask if it's going to work on mainsite. [Chat] is also a helpful resource, usually when someone's looking for a vaguer "will asking about this topic work?" up/down.

Lastly, remember that if down- or close-votes do come the way of any of your eventual questions please remember: they're not a reflection on *you*, they're a reflection on *the post*. I hope to see some posts about your game start dribbling in and hope you, too, find RPGSE to be [a healthy community full of knowledgeable, considerate people.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63626/how-do-i-cater-to-the-three-stooges-and-good-roleplayers-at-the-same-time#comment136978_63626)

Comment: Okay thank you! I think will post a rough draft in meta to see if its kosher and then see where it goes from there.