# How does one build enough reputation to respond to threads?

Tags: support, reputation

When I asked [a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126004/why-do-people-think-you-can-flank-on-a-ranged-attack-in-dd-3-5) *[auto-deleted, now only visible 10K+]* in response to not being able to respond to a question thread, my thread was stopped by site moderators as follows:

> put on hold as primarily opinion-based by Purple Monkey, Miniman, KRyan, mxyzplk♦ 8 mins ago
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise

How can I build rep through discussions if I cannot discuss here?

Answer (score 21):

The Stack Exchange model is very different from that of discussion boards. We don't really *do* discussions here. Instead, the whole thing is focused on (hard) questions and direct answers to those questions.

If you want to discuss about role-playing games that's great, and we're collected a bunch of places where you can do that [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), but this is not the place.

If you want to earn reputation on this site so you can get access to new features like commenting on other people's questions or answers, the requirement is that you show you understand how the site works by:

- asking a good, on-topic question
- providing a good, focused answer to an existing question

But even when you have some reputation and are allowed comment-privileges, you are still not supposed to discuss with people in the comment section, because that is not what it is for. The comment section is only to ask for clarification (when placed under a question) or for suggesting improvements (when placed under an answer). Other comments will usually be deleted in short order.

If you want to know more about how we work, check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help).