# Inquiring about creating an algorithm

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Based on some questions I have been poring through lately regarding the usage of Insight and Deception rolls in D&D 4E, I came across the idea to add a sort of "gambling mini-game" to my campaign for my players. What I want to do is create a rather simple algorithm, primarily using a character's Deception and Charisma scores, along with the RNG of their rolls and *something else* to create a fair algorithm -- after all, it should be something quantitative, so the players know they aren't getting cheated; who would want to gamble off the whim of someone else, after all?

Anyhow, I'd like to ask a question here regarding what else I should put in the formula. Simply saying "get a score above 20 will make you win that round of poker" is too basic, boring, and easy to manipulate. I debated posting this on StackOverflow, but because this algorithm is designed to work in a decently balanced fashion using the rules and standard practices of 4E, I figured this would be significantly more relevant here. Is such a question allowed/encouraged here? I've never seen anything on this SE related to algorithm design, as discussion is usually focused on how to best use pre-existing systems, so I figured I'd check in here first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn’t an algorithm design question, it’s an algorithm *ideas request*.

We could help with an algorithm, given available inputs and expected outputs. But we can’t help with “give me ideas for another term in the equation” — every answer is equally correct for such an answer, because they are all ideas.

Such idea-generation questions aren’t suited to SE’s Q&A design. They work fine on a discussion forum though, such as one from [our list of RPG forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321).

However, it may also be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153219): focussed on an algorithm, when the purpose of that is to solve a more fundamental problem. You could ask about the base problem instead: how to resolve a gambling game of skill. Such a question is essentially on topic (pending seeing the actual wording as usual, of course).

Comment: I suppose that's the problem with XY problems, is ye don't always notice when you've run into one. Thinking from the mindset of "how to resolve a gambling game of skill" has lead me to different questions I hadn't seen and I think I've a better direction to take this. Thanks for the input!