# How to ask about map scales?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I would like to salvage [What map scales have you found useful?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130493/what-map-scales-have-you-found-useful), which was put on hold as too opinion-based.

What would make it more acceptable?

Answer (score 5):

From our [questions to avoid asking](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help center page come some relevant guidelines:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

The whole page is worth a read, but this part is the pithiest here: what problem are you having? What current or impending situation are you dealing with that you need our expertise to help you resolve?

Tell us about that and request a solution or answer from us about how you can resolve the situation. We may tell you what map scales you should be using in the course of that.

If you don't have any particular problem to resolve then it's just a poll and there is no way for it to be on topic. You can poke us about in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) or ask on a forum: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Bear in mind the the scales are just for different maps, at different scales. What kind of map are you making? A world map, a continent map, a battle map? You're going to use different sizes. What maps someone finds useful is kinda just arbitrary depending on what scales they're operating on, so I'm not sure what kind of use you expect that poll to give you anyway.

Comment: What I'm interested in is how experienced GMs have used the three different scales and whether the scales the DMG cites, 1, 6, and 60 miles per inch, were useful, and if not what levels and scales experienced GMs have used.  I can make it about "a specific problem" if that will help.  I'm looking for the kind of experienced opinion that is often provided on designing and running games.  I'm certainly capable of trying things myself (and have), and of surveying other forums (I have), but rpg.se is by far the best expert opinion on rpgs I've found and I'd like to get that opinion on map-making.

Comment: That's definitely a [chat] or forum thing then: what you want is a poll or discussion, so you should go places that can facilitate that. While RPG.SE *is* pretty good (I agree) by design we can't be all things to all people, and we are the way we are as a result of focusing on our strong suit of focused Q&A.