# Where to post hacks?

Tags: support, dnd-5e

I have thought of no less than *three* Dungeons & Dragons 5th edition  spell hacks.
Is there anywhere on the site I can post these?

Comment: I don't understand what a 'spell hack' is. Can you give an example?

Comment: In this case, a hack would be a way to use spells that is legal but somewhat more powerful than the normal usage of the spell.

Comment: You can always hop into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) to share these and people can talk about them with you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, sorry.

This is a Q&A site, we don't have a blog or other places to post work or statements.  May I suggest one of the forum sites, see [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), or a blog.

Answer (score 9):

While this isn't a place to post them for discussion, you can post a question to verify that your "hack", or interpretation, is correct.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, in the main site.

Adhere to the Q&A format. Post a question that poses a problem that your hack solves, then post an answer yourself.

For example:

> **Q:** X spell seems too weak. Is there a scenario where this spell could be useful?
>   **A:** Yes, *[explanation]...*

Actually StackExchange [encourage sharing your expertise in this way](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). You can even gain reputation quicker by doing that! (good question+good answer)

Remember, though, that your question should still follow [the rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/asking)!

Comment: That example question is likely to be closed as POB or too broad.