# How is the community doing? [2022]

Tags: discussion, community-check-in

We, the elected moderators, wanted to take a minute to check in and see how the community feels like things are going on the site.

[This community check-in has been done for the last few years](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-check-in) (skipping 2020), and it was very helpful. As such, we'd like to share our thoughts and also get your feedback on what is going well and what we could improve. The process is modelled heavily on last year’s, but for everyone’s benefit:

### How this specific Q&A is run so that we get good value out of it

#### One clear premise per answer

1. We'll post some of the things we've done/observations we have/things we think still need improvement. Please share your thoughts as well! Make sure to note whether you think the thing you’re writing about is an improvement, a problem, or some mix of the two (one person might see the same change as bad that you see as good, or vice versa)...
2. Post only one kind of thing per answer, so that when people upvote/downvote based on whether they agree or not, it's more clearly actionable. If you write an essay about 4 different things, it's not going to be clear what part(s) people agree or disagree with and thus it becomes difficult to act on that feedback. You can, of course, contribute multiple answers.
3. Upvote or downvote the answers based on your agreement with whether you see that thing happening and whether you concur with the answer's premise (that it's good or it's a problem). (In other words, if someone says "We get too many questions about unicorns and I hate them," you would upvote if you agree, and downvote if either you don't think we get too many questions about unicorns or if you don't hate them.)

#### No long comment threads

1. This post isn't the place to workshop solutions - if a particular problem gets a lot of votes, we should open a new meta question to do justice to that issue. Solutions hidden in a comment thread on one of these answers can not be clearly vetted and voted on, so they will tend to remain undone.
2. If you disagree with an answer, use your vote, but limit comment usage. Consider that it’s possible to disagree with an answer’s take, but that it’s possible the issue should still be discussed in full.
3. If appropriate, give your own answer, though having multiple answers on the same issue here is mostly gonna be hard to follow. If the answer would just be disagreeing with another answer, the effort would probably be better placed towards a dedicated meta.

As usual, the [Code of Conduct](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/conduct), which we’d still like to summarise as Be Nice, applies to meta as well as the main site.

You may strongly disagree with other users or with the mods or whoever, but we trust that you can find ways to express what you like or don't like without being hostile or insulting to others. Focus on actions, rather than characterising people, and that extends how *how* those actions are characterised.

While we may have thoughts on things to bring up, in the interest of actually getting this started they're not gonna be here right away (read: we didn't want to delay this further in order to get those written). Hopefully others have noticed them too, and can beat us to it as well as bring up things we haven't picked up on.

Answer (score 25):

#### The repeal of the "Don't Guess the System" policy has been exceedingly successful.

The [Don't Guess the System Policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11279/what-is-the-don-t-guess-the-system-policy) was [repealed on September 3rd, 2021](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11658/revisit-iii-don-t-guess-the-system-policy/11669#11669). The process was relatively free of controversy - no proposal for maintaining the policy was made, and the highest scoring proposal for repeal is currently scored at +65/-5: a landslide. In the time since, we have handled numerous questions with an unspecified system upon posting, my estimate based on poking around with SEDE is that we have handled somewhere in the realm of 80-100 questions that did not specify the game system. Under the old policy, all of these would have been closed prior to the OP themselves clarifying the system. Instead, most of these were able to get tagged and answered without ever having to go to closure review (I've added twenty-something system tags myself). We did recently have [some discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/should-this-question-about-flying-a-broom-be-closed-for-lacking-a-system-tag) over the closure of one such question, but things were resolved in a timely manner, as is usually the case.

Overall, I would say the repeal has been a great success.

Comment: the (felt) 10-ish questions that were still closed were exceedingly bad as far as I noticed.

Answer (score 20):

#### D&D and Pathfinder questions continue to comprise nearly 90% of our questions.

| Year | D&D | PF | Total | D&D % | PF % | D&D+PF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 2756 | 948 | 4499 | 61.3% | 21.1% | 82.3% |
| 2017 | 3566 | 1300 | 5664 | 63.0% | 23.0% | 85.9% |
| 2018 | 4717 | 862 | 6257 | 75.4% | 13.8% | 89.2% |
| 2019 | 4705 | 765 | 6246 | 75.3% | 12.2% | 87.6% |
| 2020 | 3616 | 507 | 4622 | 78.2% | 11.0% | 89.2% |
| 2021 | 2272 | 496 | 3094 | 73.4% | 16.0% | 89.5% |
| 2022 | 663 | 110 | 870 | 76.2% | 12.6% | 88.9% |

As you can see, the proportion of questions related to D&D and Pathfinder games is *remarkably consistent* at just under 90% of our questions.

I'm just reporting facts here, I'll leave it to others to discuss the positives and negatives associated with these observations in their own answers.

Comment: I'm fine to have plenty of D&D questions... Is there some way of measuring views/votes etc. to gauge how welcoming the site is to non-D&D question askers?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I'm sure there is a way in SEDE, but that's outside of my wheelhouse.

Comment: It's a relief to see the numbers have been holding steady.

Comment: Here's a per-year SEDE query for D&D vs. non Qs https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/edit/1588304 and As https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/edit/1588306 -- the takeaway: in 2021 we have about 8x as many D&D questions as non D&D and they get 12x as many views. Qs score a point higher when they're non-D&D and As score a point lower, but there are roughly as many answers per question for each.

Comment: Thus far in 2022 we have 7x as many D&D vs. non-D&D questions with 15x as many views, and both Qs and As score a point higher when they're D&D.

Comment: Read "a point" as "10-15%" since scores average between 6 and 9.

Comment: Anecdotally, we seem pretty open to all RPGs.  I know as someone 98% interested in D&D, I enjoy seeing the other questions, and often learn useful things.  (Also, whoa. TIL of the existence of SEDE, available to end-users!  I could go down that rabbit hole and NEVER come back.)

Comment: @Jack You should expand that into an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing what specific systems are most popular here, maybe like a top 10 list? (That'd get beyond the inevitable 5e - PF 1/2 - 3.5e topping the list, maybe not in that order). I don't know how to SEDE that though :(

Comment: @ESCE For *all time*, you could just check the [popular tags](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) page and see what the first ten system tags are. However, the drawback there is that it does not tell you anything about the stack as it is now. 4e is the 4th most used system tag, but has only had 11 questions asked this year.

Comment: @ESCE Use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/revision/1589783/1942036/tag-yearwise) to get top tags for a given year.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov thanks! That's very helpful!!

Comment: 10-ish percent non D&D systems does not feel very welcoming. Can we estimate the average score of a D&D compared to a non d&D question per year?

Comment: Would you be able to do a 2022 review for the new round?

Comment: @Trish Yeah, I’ll work on it.

Answer (score 18):

### Activity is dwindling.

Users with the 25K privilege [Access to Site Analytics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) can see for themselves: over the last five years (pulling a number out of my wool in order to ensure we're not overwhelmed by any signal unique to spring/summer of 2020) posts are down to about 1/3 of their previous volume, views are down to about 2/3 of their previous volume.

(Anyone with that privilege and an inclination to more-rigorously crunch/present the numbers, please feel free to edit ^^.)

Anecdotally: a few months back I started to run a game in an edition (and publisher) of Traveller that was new to me. When I had questions, rather than coming here--where Traveller volume is negligible--I went to the Traveller discord where hundreds of users are on any time I've dropped a question.

It makes me wonder if an age is passing....

Comment: For myself, I'm finding it easier to ask how my GM would rule it directly than asking the community here. You could always ask and self-answer those Traveller questions, if o ever pick up the game I don't want to have to hunt through a Discord for that .

Comment: Along the lines of what @AncientSwordRage has suggested - filtering through forums or discord chats to find an answer, let alone *the* answer you need seems terrifying to me. I come here because I know what to expect - worst case scenario; I find 4 different posts dancing around the concept I'm trying to answer, but not quite hitting the nail on the head, so I ask it myself.

Comment: I should have been clearer: I don't trawl the Traveller discord for answers, I pop in and ask a simple question, get a few people chiming in within tens of minutes, and have met all my needs that way. (I'm sure it helps that Traveller is a *very* well-established franchise. Then again, I'd be shocked if the Storyteller or PbtA or FATE discords weren't similarly friendly and active.)

Comment: Yes but for the next person asking the same question; they would have to do the trawling; that's where this site comes in handy

Comment: @Ben Both this site and Discord have search functions. Discords often even have channels *exclusively* for rules questions, so searches can be limited quite well. That said, searching through Discord would likely be more difficult due to one thing: a lack of tags

Comment: The edition that created an explosion around the time you and I joined up is reaching it's mid life crisis (5.5e is lurking, eh?) and we have accumulated a decent library of asked and answered questions.  Which means that the intent of this stack is being met: useful answers are already there rather than being crafted.   But there are also other venues where similar discourse goes on. When this site started, Discord (among others) was nowhere near as robust as it is now. Also massively jealous that you get to play Traveller. 

Comment: @KorvinStarmast By decent library, you mean *over 20,000 questions* :P

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes, though I am not sure if dupes are counted inside of that number or are excluded from it.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast We have [17,236](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D+closed%3A0+locked%3A0) non-closed, non-locked D&D 5e questions right now.

Comment: I personally stopped using the stack as much as I did after the whole situation with one of the mods of Workplace a while ago. It made me rather upset at how Stack Exchange as a company handled things, and made me lose faith in the site in general. Now I just pop in here every now and then.

Comment: I've not been around long enough to know, could this be related to how strict we are in regulating participation? For example, I could see that with 17K answered questions, it may be quite a bit harder to ask one that has not been answered before now, and may lead to a lot of first time querants having an unpleasant experience when they try. Do we have statistics on the ratio of posed to closed questions over time, or on how likely people are to participate after their early questions get closed?

Comment: Because the people on this forum make it extremely unwelcome to anyone who asks a question. If someone doesn't use perfect grammar or they're even slightly vague in part of their question, people immediately vote to close it. Plus they're jerks about their answers half the time. If you ask a simple question that people aren't immediately enthralled by, they down vote it to oblivion and treat you like you're an idiot. What use is a question forum if you can't ask questions? That's why traffic has slowed down so much over the years

Answer (score 15):

As far as I can see, my reasons for no longer posting here have not changed. I come back every few weeks and up/down tick question or answers of interest to me, but can no longer see the point in actually using the site in any other way. There are better forums when if you ask a question you are not treated as some student that needs to learn how to ask a correct question. The fact that there was even rules about "having to specify the system" when someone might have wanted a general answer, or "asking about designer intent", is all part of the unfriendliness that I and others pointed out many years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Upvoting/Downvoting questions is still a valid and appreciated way of using the site, and the note that you don't see the point in using the site any other way is something I think as a site and community we should take on board. When you say  "having to specify the system" do you mean the recently repealed "don't guess the system" policy or more the idea that a system tag is so key that one must be used?

Comment: I agree that "Asking about designer intent" is a tricky one. On the one hand we had too many speculative answers for D&D where the *actual* intent was super unclear. For other systems it's a useful concept! I wish we had an easy way around it

Comment: If the question is "How do I kill my enemy?" then the answer for Traveller is quite different from D&D5e which is different from [PPP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCsch,_Power_%26_Plunder) where the answer is "You don't, you cuddle!"

Comment: I emphasize with this. My impression is that the bar for getting a question closed is too low. Between "Opinion Based", and "Need Focus" (even when similar open questions exist), it can be difficult to get a question posted if someone opts to oppose it, and it really feels quite arbitrary. Likewise, the bar for "Duplicate" seems very low. It may be that is all as intended and helps to make the site better. For me closure discussions although civil in tone, have been a majorly negative experience, and I can easily see someone give up and not return.

Comment: I agree with the better forum part of this answer, but I don't think that this makes the stack any less valuable as a resource. The stack does some things very well, and in other areas, it is unusable. I think it is acceptable to require multiple tailored venues to get the desired feedback. The built in system doesn't always feel pleasant, but it delivers results and that is desirable.

Comment: I once went to Waffle House with my kid brother, and he insisted on ordering pancakes, which Waffle House obviously does not have. He was remarkably upset about this, and decided it was Waffle House's fault he was upset and that Waffle House needed to change. I think about this sometimes on the stack when I see users who come to the stack expecting an open ended discussion forum, when that's just not what this place is.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the difference being that Waffle House didn't have 5-6 wait staff come up to your kid brother and say "We don't do pancakes!" all at once. At least I hope not.

Comment: The Waffle House thing sent me down an internet rabbit hole.  Waffle House *could* have pancakes.  They have eggs, biscuits, steak, hamburgers, chili, chicken, etc.  IHOP has waffles.... I mean, a chef could throw some waffle batter on the grill and *make* a pancake. "Here, kid, here's your pancake!" (I know, I know, there's reasons they don't or shouldn't or whatever; it's a surprisingly deep rabbit hole.)  Still, ThomasMarkov I get your point, and it's a good one. But also AncientSwordRage has a pretty good point, too.

Comment: @Jack You haven’t been down the Waffle House rabbit hole until you’ve heard [Raisins in My Toast](https://youtu.be/N_LnuPFnJXY).

Comment: Anyone with feelings (in any direction) on @ThomasMarkov's apt Waffle House metaphor should consider [this meta.SO answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366947/7317818) required reading, IMO.

Comment: Pretty sure that this Waffle House did used to sell pancakes before.

Comment: Judging from the number of Up/Downvotes here, this seems to be **the most controversial question of the bunch**. My impression is that there are two viewpoints on this: the OPs, and an opposing one that it is needed and correct to enforce these standards on question asking, even at the risk of alienating (especially new) querants. Or maybe, with the purposeful intent to get rid of querants that struggle to meet the imposed quality criteria for their questions.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin and this why I don't find this place friendly any more and don't use it. I am heartened that 2/3 seam to agree with me.

Comment: @DavidAllanFinch I upvoted you because I wanted to acknowledge the distress caused by *how* certain rules/policies/expected behaviours have been enforced but I don't think I disagree with them in principle. At the moment you're at +16 and -7, so more than a few people agree with you

Comment: @DavidAllanFinch Agree 100% What you describe matches my experience. This just seem a very unfriendly space - and I am leaving it.

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – see [Are questions about rule intent on-topic? [2022]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12157/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic-2022)

#### Rule intent questions?

It is a bit disappointing how long it has taken to get a verdict on rule intent questions. The scores settled on the meta over two months ago, with votes currently sitting at an overwhelmingly positive +27/-1 in favor of ["On this one, I think it actually should be up to ♦ mods"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11953/62294). A month ago, in [this comment](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/how-can-i-ask-a-good-designer-intent-question#comment41495_12013) linksassin stated:

> we are in favour of seeing them return in some form but haven't reached a consensus on what that will look like,

indicating some level of general agreement about the direction to go. This comment was on this post, [How can I ask a good designer intent question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/how-can-i-ask-a-good-designer-intent-question), which was closed, with myself and doppelgreener providing close reasons in comments:

> I’m voting to close this question because for now, designer intent questions are off topic, so the only answer to this question is “you can’t”. The mods have said nothing about permitting these questions again, so we should wait until they make that decision and hear what they have to say about it before we try to write guidance. – [Thomas Markov Mar 22 at 22:22](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/how-can-i-ask-a-good-designer-intent-question#comment41491_12013)

> I agree this is a little premature to ask. They're not allowed right now so this is jumping the gun; if they stay gone then no guidance is relevant and the effort is wasted. Moreover the nature of their return will inform how we handle this kind of discussion. KRyan's argued that "designer intent" is not even well-defined in our current community operation. Will we deprecate its use as a concept? The way forward for how we even frame approaching this issue again is yet to be fully determined, whether by the mods or anyone else. Mods might lead that discussion but we should have it first. – [doppelgreener Mar 23 at 3:13](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12013/how-can-i-ask-a-good-designer-intent-question#comment41494_12013)

Linksassin's comment from above continues:

> However I'm not opposed to the existence of this question, an answer guiding what the community feels a good 'designer intent' question looks like may help shape how we approach this moving forward. It would also keep us accountable to actually getting this done.

I went on to suggest that meta was already slow enough, and that we shouldn't wait on guidance to take shape before making a ruling on rule intent questions; link responded:

> Didn't mean to imply that we would wait on this meta, sorry if it came across that way. I meant that the community (if it wanted to) could use this meta to get started on creating the guidance which will be required while we are still dragging out feet trying to get organised. Basically, we will keep moving forward, if someone makes a good answer here we might take that into account but it (hopefully) won't change the timeline either way.

So do we need to reopen Akixkisu's question and move the discussion along as link suggested? Is there something we can do to help you guys move this one along?

Comment: If the mods aren't sure how to proceed but are generally in favour of bringing them back in some form, perhaps it would be appropriate for the mods to bring this back to the community: we want to proceed in this direction, here's what we've already determined, here's where we're stuck, how should we handle this together? That would bring us back to the kind of platform Akixkisu was aiming to provide, but one informed by the current state of affairs. I'd recommend this even if the mod team's no further than the decision to bring them back somehow; there's no shame in being stuck on this one.

Comment: Could we at least get a comment from a moderator here? It's been nine days since I posted this and none of the moderators felt compelled to acknowledge it with a comment, so my disappointment continues to grow.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I would rather they took a month to reply than rushed a response. That said a "We're working on an reply" comment would work in the mean time

Comment: @AncientSwordRage It’s been 75 days. They have already taken two and a half months to reply.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I was solely referring to "It's been nine days since I posted this and none of the moderators ...".

Comment: We are kicking around some thoughts on this topic. It had drifted towards the back burner due to some other issues that came up since the meta question on the topic, but this answer has pushed it back towards the top of our to-do list.

Answer (score 6):

#### Our forum index hasn't been updated in over two years.

We have a handy dandy [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/62294) that we use to direct off topic questions. The last time it was substantially updated was March of 2020 (see [revision 10](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/9335/10)), with the removal of the dead Story Games Forums.

I quite literally know nothing about other RPG forums, so find myself ill equipped for reviewing the list outside of checking for dead links. It would be great if some of y'all<sup>1</sup> could give the index a little audit, checking for dead links, URL changes, forum shutdowns, unfortunate changes in attitude toward minority groups, etc. And if you are aware of any good candidates to add to the list, propose them in answer so the community can vet and vote.

---

<sup>1 A contraction meaning "you all", here referring to any reader, not just "you all the mods".</sup>

Comment: A relevant Meta post from 2019: [Proposal to reboot our forum list](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9304/33569) - Some responses there favored curating/updating the existing forum list, while others favored deprecating the existing list and starting a new one. (This eventually resulted in the consolidation of recommended forums into one answer, rather than a bunch of separate answers.)

Answer (score 4):

#### The FAQ proposal process is still kind of in limbo, and has been for a long time.

See: [FAQ Proposal Index for Role-playing Games Stack Exchange](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/faq-proposal-index-for-role-playing-games-stack-exchange)

I've made this observation before in chat ([here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=57647222#57647222), [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57085376#57085376), [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59733364#59733364)). I think it's time to try something new for FAQ proposals. The current process is not working because of a lack of participation. I don't have any ideas at the moment. But maybe we can have a brainstorming discussion soon...

Comment: Right now posts sit until they're approved and there's no other outcome, meaning posts that aren't approved stick around for eternity. One way to take things out of limbo would be to decline them after a time limit, like a month, and delete the proposal post.

Comment: @doppelgreener I’d like to see a solution where we delete proposals because the community voted them down, not because nobody really checked.

Comment: Well my reasoning here is that if the community isn't interested in having it as an FAQ proposal after two(!!) years, it's not interested in having it as an FAQ proposal, regardless of the score. In practice the many that got accepted were accepted inside of a month. "Actively declined" and "no interest" are both outcomes that should be considered a rejection. Meanwhile, if the proposal Q maintains only fresh live proposals, then anyone visiting the thread will be browsing a couple of fresh proposals, not several they've seen before with fresh ones mixed in among them they might not even spot.

Comment: Related Meta posts: [What's the actual process around \[faq-proposal\]s?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6510/33569) (a question from 2016), [FAQ Proposal Index for Role-playing Games Stack Exchange](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9961/33569) (a more recent trial process from 2020)

Comment: @doppelgreener I would completely agree with you if I was confident the community was interested in the FAQ proposal at all. "Didn't get enough upvotes" isn't a good enough metric if the reason is a lack of participation in general, rather than a lack of support for a particular proposal.

Comment: Well, there's kind of a catch 22 here then: we can't tell the difference between "the community paid attention but isn't interested" and "the community didn't pay attention and isn't interested." I believe the existing evidence of interaction says it's the former, but more importantly I believe keeping the slate clean with only new proposals will (1) facilitate more interest and (2) get people who want it to pass to generate that interest, attracting more votes one way or another. I'm not suggesting the decline be permanent and binding, but if someone feels strongly they can re-raise it.