# Is there a dedicated place within RPG SE for users to post source codes or helpful spreadsheets that they made/use to share the love to other users?

Tags: discussion

I play a summoning focused druid in my 3.5e campaign and handling multiple summons and math on the fly with all the augments got tiresome - I couldn't find a helpful sheet for animal/creature templates, so I decided to try to make one (.NET, C#). It's a work in progress, but I want to share the source code when/if it's workable and/or "finished."

So, rpg friends, is there a dedicated place for this? Where do I look when I want to do some looking, and/or where do I throw my links/sheets when I want to share the love? If I see there's a preference among the community for prefer sheets instead of source code, I'd shift my work towards getting it into a sheets format.

Screenshot for the idea of the program/progress

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is not.

Feel free and put them in a blog and link it in your profile.  And mention it in chat.  And link a specific item into an answer if it is part of a good answer (make sure and disclose it’s yours).

Answer (score 13):

The best approach is probably to do a self-answered Q&A along the lines of “how do I managed all my summons?” and then answer with “use this app I wrote,” with the actual code probably hosted on GitHub or wherever unless it’s rather shorter than I imagine it would be.

A meta post collection of useful tools users here have made could maybe be done, though I don’t know how many others there are. Considering the breadth of RPG materials out there, though, it might be somewhat unwieldy.

Comment: This would be my go to way. Also it allow other answers to thrives. Alternatives are always good.

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe it belongs on RPG.SE.

Instead I would consult our [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449) and share it in one of them, this also has the benefit of more people being likely to see it.

Comment: There’s also overlap in the communities, so posting on a forum doesn’t necessarily mean the RPG.se community will be deprived of the material.