# Can I ask for item ideas focused around a specific theme?

Tags: discussion, questions

The theme I have in mind specifically that causes my question is that I want to ask for item ideas I can drop into a DnD 5e campaign that are easter-egg items for star wars, but nothing as blatant as, say, a lightsaber.

I know on other Stack Exchange sites, "Idea Generation" type questions are not allowed in any sort of manner. Is that true here as well?

Comment: Thank you for asking us on meta first. It is so much nicer to upvote a meta question, than to vote-to-close a question on main.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going to reddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/f6wes8/dnd_5e_easter_egg_item_ideas_in_star_wars_theme/

Answer (score 13):

## It's true here aswell

The problem with Idea Generation questions is that they don't work with the Stack Exchange *format* (Q&A with good answers being upvoted), because there is no way to tell what a good answer is. Or seen another way, the response a idea generation querent wants is not a single, clear answer, but a (infinite) spread of suggestions they can frolic in.

If you want such a spread of responses with little to no vote-biasing etc. traditional forums are really good for that, so it is better for everyone to use that format for those kind of queries. We maintain a [curated list here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137) and if you want suggestions from some of the same thinking organs as are kicking around here, you can try [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) (which doesn't have the same topic and question restrictions as main, but we do require you to Be Nice).

Comment: (safety note: please don't kick around thinking organs.)

Answer (score 4):

### RPGSE chat is an option for idea generation

You have enough rep to ask for a brain storm in [RPGSE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).
[With 20 rep or more, one can participate in a site's chat room](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).
That's a good place to pick brains, but who is there at a given time will vary.