# Isn't my question about LARP opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Two years ago, I asked a question: [How do I get my players' LARP characters to not be a bunch of murderous cretins?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122193/30214)

It was about a problem that most Russian LARPers know about, a very practical problem. The answers were very helpful, and since then, I have also discovered some solutions myself.

Now, rereading the answers, I notice many of them look:

1. Non-mutually-exclusive
2. Equally valid

You can use them all in your LARP practice at the same time, and it will work (I noticed that most good LARP games used most or all of the tips). None is then worse or better than another. Hence, this question looks better suited for a forum, where it could collect answers eternally for the help of future LARP GMs.

So, should it be closed and [redirected to a forum or a forum-like space?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/30214)

Comment: What makes you think that "non-mutually exclusive" and "equally valid" make the question primarily opinion-based? I don't really see how the answers all being applicable makes the question close-worthy; if anything, it ostensibly suggests that they're good answers (or is one aspect of a good answer, at least).

Comment: @V2Blast I believe it's likely because the "[Don't Ask](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" page says: "[...] Avoid asking subjective questions where...: every answer is equally valid [...]" Though I believe this "every" means "every possible answer" and not "every current answer", since this one would certainly fall under [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: @Medix2 that is exactly my interpretation-- having two or more equally valid answers does not make a question bad or inherently opinion-based.  Having a question which can ONLY generate answers which are ALL equally valid does.

Answer (score 12):

Can a question draw meaningful votes from experts, who can judge an answer and say “that’s a good idea” or “that’s a bad one”? Then it’s fine.

Questions are closed primarily because they prevent voting from working correctly, and do not allow the site’s mechanisms for generating a high signal-to-noise ratio (i.e. voting) to actually accomplish that goal (i.e. the votes just become a popularity contest, or just literally everything gets upvoted). The goal, in effect, is to ensure that *votes* have a high signal-to-noise ratio, where the “signal” is “this is actually helpful” and the “noise” is anything else—random chance, personal preference, and so on.

Since your question could easily draw ideas that are not good, and which experts can recognize as such, and also draw distinctly-superior approaches, the odds are pretty good that it isn’t *primarily* opinion-based. Remember that word “primarily,” because it’s crucial—questions which are seeking the educated, expert opinion of those who have experienced and solved similar issues aren’t *primarily* opinion-based, they’re **precisely what the site is best at**. Questions that are *primarily* opinion-based, on the other hand, are just matters of preference, and often, situations where anyone could throw their two cents in and be just as “right” as any “expert,” because it’s a question where expertise doesn’t come into play. Those are the questions we close.

Comment: Right, remember the word primarily even though it is no longer on the close reason. It's really good for describing when it is we need to close for that reason.