# Are questions about the viability of a campaign or mission's premise acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, close-reasons

I'm currently in the early stages of planning a campaign where my current idea is that the PCs will be travelling over a large continent, and the primary thing keeping them together is a curse that requires them to not go too far apart. I'm not sure how good of an idea this is, so I was thinking of asking about it here.

However, I'm not sure if this would fall under the "opinion-based" question category, which is reason enough for questions to be closed.

Is this a question that would be on-topic for the RPG Stack Exchange, or should I take it somewhere else?

Comment: I'd suggest posting the full question in here as you'd post it and mention the system as well. This seems borderline enough that wording is important - "How to do X" is a lot more Stackable than "Is X a good idea", for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## This will likely be opinion based

If I'm reading it correctly your proposed question is something along the lines of:

> Is it a good idea for a campaign to have the party cursed such that they cannot go too far apart?

#### Problems that make this a poor SE question

As stated your question has a number of problems, mostly to do with insufficient detail. If you edit this question to include the full text of your proposed question it will likely address most of these.

- How far is too far? You will need to define the relative distance allowed between victims of the curse. 30ft is a very different discussion to 10 miles for instance.
- How is the curse enforced? What is preventing the PCs from simply ignoring this curse?
- Is breaking the curse the main premise of the campaign? Or will there be other plot lines and the curse is merely there to prevent splitting the party or coming up with a better reason for them to want to work together?

To remain as an open question you will likely need to address most of the points above, as well as any that get raised in comments on the question.

#### It's still likely opinion based

Our opinion-based closed reason states:

> This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Unless you can state the question in a form that will attract factual answers it will likely be closed as opinion based. *"Is X a good idea?"* will almost always be opinion based. However it is possible to form a question such as *"What additional challenges will this curse pose for my party?"* or similar where you focus on the mechanical limitations your curse imposes and how you might prepare for or mitigate those issues. How you tailor this will depend on exactly what kind of answer you are trying to get out of this.

#### Try a forum or chatroom

Ultimately it is possible to get this question into a format that could be asked on SE, however by that point it is likely no longer asking what you really wanted to ask. I gather you just want to bounce your idea of the collective wisdom of the community and get some feedback before going to far down the rabbit hole. That kind of discussion is much better suited to our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat) or to one of our [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). Good luck, hope you find the answers you want.

Comment: IMO, not really opinion-based. Although, I can really see why it can be called such. With that said, were the question to be asked, I'd say it's just not very interesting. Players will either cooperate or not. Adding some mechanics to make them cooperate is just bad as it presupposes they won't. Which, if true, won't really work out in the long term. A much better question would be "how to make players cooperate". And would probably include details about the group and why might they choose *not* to cooperate. New players? Playing evil campaign? Character incompatibilities? Etc.

Comment: @VLAZ "Is X a good idea?" without criteria to assess what makes something a good idea is basically the definition of opinion based. Agree with your suggestions of what would be a better question though.